# Entity Framework The underlying provider failed on Open Asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Following connection string. On project sometime this error occurred. Entity Framework The underlying provider failed on Open.Please help me to sort out this issue. Is this sql server issue or entity framework issue or connection string issue?

I am using sql server management studio 2012. This error sometimes occur and sometimes it does not occur.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQL0001.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B08A4_demoCSEZONE;User Id=DB_9B08A4_demoCSEZONE_admin;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="dbCseZoneEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EntitiesCseZone.csdl|res://*/Models.EntitiesCseZone.ssdl|res://*/Models.EntitiesCseZone.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SQL0001.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B08A4_demoCSEZONE;User Id=DB_9B08A4_demoCSEZONE_admin;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: nice password in your post!

Comment: Please delete this question or change that password.

Comment: Most of the time, it is a connection string problem when you get that error. Did you use the Entity framework wizard to create that connection string ?